# Freeing dynamically allocated int that needs to be returned but cannot be freed in main in c

Tags: c, memory-leaks, free

As my long title says: I am trying to return a pointer in c that has been dynamically allocated, I know, I have to free it, but I do not know how to myself, my search has showed that it can only be freed in main, but I cannot leave it up to the user to free the int.

My code looks like this right now,

```
int *toInt(BigInt *p)
{
    int *integer = NULL;

    integer = calloc(1, sizeof(int));

    // do some stuff here to make integer become an int from a passed
    // struct array of integers

    return integer;
}
```

I've tried just making a temp variable and seeing the integer to that then freeing integer and returning the temp, but that hasn't worked. There must be a way to do this without freeing in main?

Comment: I don't know what you searched, but you can free allocated memory pretty much anywhere, not just in the main.

Comment: if you pass the result of maloc() / calloc() as a return value in general you cannot know what the caller does with that pointer and thus you should leave it to the caller to free it if it's no longer needed

Comment: I mean to say, if i return an unfreed pointer like I have above, the only way to free it would be to either free it directly in main like: free(integer); or call another function that frees it, either way, it'd have to be in main

Comment: no - you can definitely free the memory at any point in your code after it's been allocated as long as you keep track of the pointer.

Comment: @ChrisTurner I don't have a very good handle on pointers, If i make this pointer how can I track the pointer and return that, after its been freed?

Comment: Why can't it be `freed` in `main`? Blink with your eyes if someone is standing behind you with a gun. Otherwise you should consult a good C book about pointers and dynamic memory allocation. I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: @Olaf Because that's shitty design which leads to memory leaks?

Comment: When your code calls toInt() it stores the returned value (the pointer) into another variable of type `int *`. You can later on pass that variable to `free()` to free the memory you allocated earlier.

Comment: @Lundin: We don't see the whole code. Could well be there are only two functions in the program: this one and `main` and only a single module. I'd be careful to call something "shitty" unless I have the full picture (or at least a wide-enough picture). We need a [mcve] first. (oh, and "cannot" is not the same as "should not").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your particular code gains nothing useful from dynamic allocation, as @unwind already observed.  You can save yourself considerable trouble by just avoiding it.

In a more general sense, you should imagine that with each block of allocated memory is associated an implicit obligation to free.  There is no physical or electronic representation of that obligation, but you can imagine it as a virtual chit associated at any given time with at most one copy of the pointer to the space during the lifetime of the allocation.  You can transfer the obligation between  copies of the pointer value at will.  If the pointer value with the obligation is ever lost through going out of scope or being modified then you have a leak, at least in principle; if you free the space via a copy of the pointer that does not at that time hold the obligation to free, then you have a (possibly virtual) double free.

> I know I have to free it, but I do not know how to myself

A function that allocates memory and returns a copy of the pointer to it without making any other copies, such as your example, should be assumed to associate the obligation to free with the returned pointer value.  It cannot free the allocated space itself, because that space must remain allocated after the function returns (else the returned pointer is worse than useless).  If the obligation to free were not transferred to the returned pointer then a (virtual) memory leak would occur when the function's local variables go out of scope at its end, leaving no extant copy of the pointer having obligation to free.

> I cannot leave it up to the user to free the int.

If you mean you cannot leave it up to the *caller*, then you are mistaken.  Of course you *can* leave it up to the caller.  If in fact the function allocates space and returns a pointer to it as you describe, then it *must* transfer the obligation to free to the caller along with the returned copy of the pointer to the allocated space.  That's exactly what the `calloc()` function does in the first place.  Other functions do similar, such as POSIX's `strdup()`.

Because there is no physical or electronic representation of obligation to free, it is essential that your functions *document* any such obligations placed on the caller.

Comment: Great answer John.

Answer (score 5):

Program design-wise, you should always let the "module" (translation unit) that did the allocation be responsible for freeing the memory. Expecting some other module or the caller to free() memory is indeed bad design.

Unfortunately C does not have constructors/destructors (nor "RAII"), so this has to be handled with a separate function call. Conceptually you should design the program like this:

```
#include "my_type.h"

int main()
{
  my_type* mt = my_type_alloc();
  ...
  my_type_free(mt);
}
```

---

As for your specific case, there is no need for dynamic allocation. Simply leave allocation to the caller instead, and use a dedicated error type for reporting errors:

```
err_t toInt (const BigInt* p, int* integer)
{
   if(bad_things())
     return ERROR;

   *integer = p->stuff();

   return OK;
}
```

Where `err_t` is some custom error-handling type (likely enum).

Comment: I understand how that is a better approach, but I'm under specific restrictions to: Convert the integer represented by p to a dynamically allocated int, and return a pointer to that value. If p is NULL, simply return NULL. If the integer represented by p exceeds the maximum int value defined in limits.h, return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Just stop treating it as a pointer, there's no need for a single `int`.

Return it directly, and there will be no memory management issues since it's automatically allocated:

```
int toInt(const BigInt *p)
{
  int x;
  x = do some stuff;
  return x;
}
```

The caller can just do

```
const int my_x = toInt(myBigInt);
```

and `my_x` will be automatically cleaned away when it does out of scope.

Comment: The sole reason this function returns a pointer instead of an int is so that I can return NULL to signify failure in cases where p cannot be represented as an int. Like if the array to be converted is bigger than 2 ^ 31 - 1

Comment: @GrahamChapman That still wouldn't justify your allocation for one int. If you want to check limits, why not compare with  `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` from `limits.h`?

Comment: Would it be more approriate to use malloc(sizeof(int)) instead of calloc? All I know is I have to convert the integer represented by p to a dynamically allocated int and return a pointer to that value.

Comment: @GrahamChapman, if indeed the only reason to use a pointer is to afford the opportunity to communicate an error by returning `NULL`, then perhaps you should consider signaling errors via a different means.  For example, make the function return a success code, and have it provide the actual converted value via an output parameter.  Or return a structure containing both a success code and a converted value, with the latter being meaningless in the case of failure.